# Using spring boot & parallel streams to send emails

Tags: java, spring-boot, email, parallel-processing

I am trying to send email using spring-boot but send it using parallel streams so that it is not synchronized. 
Can anyone point me in the right direction with code.

This is what I have so far -

```
for (String toAddress : emailDto.getToEmailAddresses())  {
   message = new SimpleMailMessage();
   message.setTo(toAddress);
   message.setSubject(emailDto.getSubject());
   message.setText(emailDto.getBody());
   message.setFrom(fromAddress);
   emailSender.send(message);
   _logger.info("Send Email successfully to " + toAddress);
}
```

I am trying to do something along these lines- 
toAddresses.parallelStream().forEach(System.out::println);
But use parallel stream to send each email.

Comment: Consider having a dedicated mailserver responsible for delivering mail, and then just send to that.  Then you don’t need parallel streams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SimpleMailMessage.setTo](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mail/SimpleMailMessage.html#setTo-java.lang.String-) already has the case for multiple addresses so you could simply write

```
message.setTo(emailDto.getToEmailAddresses().toArray(new String[0]))
```

Comment: Does the javaMailSender send emails parallelly and not sequentially?

Comment: javaMailSender sends mail in a synchronous way. It waits until confirmation from the mail server.

Comment: To make it asynchronous just wrap the emailSender in a Runnable class and use a java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService. By the way, going on this path, it would be worth to fix the timeout, in spring properties, like mail.smtps.timeout=1000